# find with several arguments to -name

Tags: shell, find

I read the manual, searched the internet, but no solution. I want to grep through all markdown files:

```
find . -iname "*.md" -exec grep -I "foo" {} \;
```

But how to add all "*.adoc" files same time? In the manual of `find` is an example:

```
find / \( -newer ttt -or -user wnj \) -print
```

I tried every possibility based on this example to no avail.

Sorry for this simplistic question.

marek

Comment: `find . \( -iname "*.md" -or -iname "*.adoc" \)  -exec ...` maybe?

Comment: Thank you Mark. I tried this one too! But now it is working. Sometimes I need to restart my Shell, to make it work. My result is as follows now: `find . \( -iname "*.md" -or -iname "*.adoc" \) -exec grep -C 2 -H -i "foo" {} \; | less`